# How to exclude category and post_tag taxonomy while displaying custom taxonomy?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, tags

The code i'm using for displaying custom taxonomies is as below:

```
function custom_taxonomies_terms_links(){
  // get post by post id
  $post = get_post( $post->ID );

  // get post type by post
  $post_type = $post->post_type;

  // get post type taxonomies
  $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'objects' );

  $out = array();
  foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy_slug => $taxonomy ){

    // get the terms related to post
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_slug );

    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
      $out[] = "<br/>".$taxonomy->label . " : ";
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $out[] =
          '  <a href="'
        .    get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy_slug ) .'">'
        .    $term->name
        . "</a>";
      }
      $out[] = " ";
    }
  }

  return implode('', $out );
}
```

However it is also showing the category taxonomies and tag taxonomies, which are default taxonomies and i only want to display the custom ones. Which modification of the code should i make? I tried to create an arraty using category and post_tag slugs and used array_diff, but it didn't work cause there is some array vs object conflict happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each taxonomy object will have `_builtin` set to `1` for native taxonomies, so check `$taxonomy->_builtin` in your `foreach` loop first before fetching the terms.